# Time Series Insert

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

This is a shrunken down version of a previously deleted post. I have read other post and the orientdb wiki along with the linkedin presentation. Not getting past my current progress.

My question is 2 fold.

**1)** What is the proper way and best practices in linking data to time series classes.

**2)** Can this be done with a hook at time of insert ?

Below you will find the source data model, time series classes and a diagram.

The data model is constantly being updated and gerates a few million records a day.

***Source Data Model***

```
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#507:788457",
            "@version": 2,
            "@class": "Live",
            "MarketName": "BTC-OMNI",
            "High": 0.01398825,
            "Low": 0.0117,
            "Volume": 1121.38384722,
            "Last": 0.01254396,
            "Bid": 0.01219709,
            "Ask": 0.01254377,
            "BaseVolume": 14.52156426,
            "TimeStamp": "2017-07-28T16:51:07.853",
            "year": 2017,
            "month": 7,
            "day": 28,
            "hour": 16,
            "minute": 51
            "@fieldTypes": "High=d,Low=d,Volume=d,Last=d,Bid=d,Ask=d,BaseVolume=d,Year=d,Month=d,Day=d,Hour=d,Minute=d"
        }
```

**Time Series classes**

```
CREATE CLASS Year
CREATE CLASS Month
CREATE CLASS Day
CREATE CLASS Hour
CREATE CLASS Minute
```

**Diagram of what I am trying to achieve**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using orientjs livequery.

Can someone confirm whether or not this is a sound way to do this?

have a live query listening for inserts into your source class, update the time series table on insert.

All of the time series classes are getting updated with the source records on insert.

```
db.liveQuery('LIVE SELECT FROM live ')

   .on('live-insert', function(data){
        var r = data.cluster;
        var id = data.position;
        var rid = '#'+r+':'+id;


        var umin = 'update Year set month[' + data.content.month + '].day[' + data.content.day + '].hour[' + shour + '].minute[' + data.content.minute + '].live = ' + rid + ' where year = ' + data.content.year
        var uhour = 'update Year set month[' + data.content.month + '].day[' + data.content.day + '].hour[' + shour + '].live = ' + rid + ' where year = ' + data.content.year
        var uday = 'update Year set month[' + data.content.month + '].day[' + data.content.day + '].live = ' + rid + ' where year = ' + data.content.year
        var umon = 'update Year set month[' + data.content.month + '].live = ' + rid + ' where year = ' + data.content.year  

        db.query(umin)
            .then((updatedmin) => {console.log('updated minutes')})
        db.query(uhour)
            .then((updatedhour) => {console.log('updated hours')})
        db.query(uday)
            .then((updateday) => {console.log('updated day')})
        db.query(umon)
            .then((updatedmon) => {console.log('updated month')})



   });
```